# Unwanted server access

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, amazon-web-services, rdp

I have blocked the RDP to be only posssible via a specific IP address . For that purpose i have done it through the security groups of Aamazon EC2.

However i noticied that someone is still trying to access the server via RDP and getting access denied .

Normally if you do such configuration above the AWS security groups servers send the deny reponse to the requestor and the request does  not reach your server .

Do you have any explanations ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your security group settings for the instance?

Comment: i added the inbound rules

Comment: This is a Logon Type 3 logon attempt, which is a network logon. Logon Type 10 would be a RemoteInteractive (TS, RDS, RA) logon attempt, so these logon attempts are not RDP logon attempts. I noticed you have port 1433 and port 1434 open for SQL Server. This might be an attempt to logon to SQL Server.

Comment: All right thank you for the clarifications really helping.

Comment: I tested to see what logon type will be put if i try to access with bad password . The result is windows server logs it as logon type 3 and not 10 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any port open to the general public a part form the port 80 or 443 . All other ports should be configured in the security groups on Amazon EC2 to be accessed from a specific IP .